# How to fix Tweepy error 'Sorry, that page does not exist.' in suggested_users()

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy==3.6.0 and Python 3.6

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,
                          access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# categories = api.suggested_categories()
users = api.suggested_users(slug='science')
```

`suggested_users()` raises this error:

> raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
>   tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page 
>   does not exist.'}]

Comment: Based on the [Twitter API reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index), it seems that `GET users/suggestions`, `GET users/suggestions/:slug` and `GET users/suggestions/:slug/members` are deprecated.

Comment: but they will close this route after 30 July

Comment: and api.suggested_categories() also working

Comment: This API will be gone after June 30th 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [Twitter API reference](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-suggestions-slug), `GET users/suggestions/:slug` is used to:

> Access the users *in a given category of the Twitter suggested user list*.

So, when using `api.suggested_users()`, you cannot specify an arbitrary category like 'science'. You need to take the category slug from one of the suggested categories, which you can retrieve with `api.suggested_categories()`.

Here's a working example that lists the users of the 1st suggested category (with `categories[0].slug`):

```
categories = api.suggested_categories(lang='en')
# print names and slugs of suggested categories
for cat in categories:
    print(cat.name,' - ',cat.slug)

users = api.suggested_users(slug=categories[0].slug, lang='en')
# print id and screen names of suggested users
for user in users:
    print(user.id, ' - ', user.screen_name)
```

Comment: As announced on April 19th 2019, this function will no longer be available after June 30th 2019.